# On demand drilldown report in SSRS 2008

Tags: .htaccess, ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

We can implement drilldown report using grouping feature of SSRS 2008, where we just give SSRS filtered data and group expression and rest is done by SSRS, great. Our problem is that we have very large data even after giving filter, so it takes lot of time for SSRS to get data and group it. What can be ideal situation is that we have opportunity to really implement drill down, i mean when user expand group level 1 , group level 2 data is fetched from DB by SSRS and rendered and delivered to client.

We tried with subreports but then again it preloads data. and we have to provide up to 8 levels of drill down.

Any suggestion how to do it in SSRS 2008 is welcomed, any alternative approach suggestion is welcomed as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the "Link to Report" feature in one of your columns.  This way you can create a summary report, and then fire off another report when the user clicks the columns row data.  The drill down report can accept a parameter from the main report to determine what data should display.